# Text processing before printing in awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am not into scripting but manage to create few with the help in this forum. Coming across a problem but not able to get it work (not sure if it is possible)

I have a fileY with content

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1  user1 gp  35  2021-09-07  2000  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt
lrwxrwxrwx  1  user1 gp  35  2021-09-08  1400  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt
lrwxrwxrwx  1  user1 gp  35  2021-09-09  1800  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt
```

I wanted to output the column 3,6,7,8 and concatenate with the folder name before "main" like below

```
user1 2021-09-07  2000  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08  1400  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09  1800  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```

How can i have below **sed** command as one of the {print} variable for awk command?

```
awk '{print $3,$6,$7,$8}' fileY
sed 's/\// /g; s/\./ /g' fileY | awk '{for(i=8;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^main/){a=i}} print $(a-1)}'
```

Comment: Noted @Ed Morton. Sorry for it. Will start a new thread for a new questions in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never need sed when you're using awk. If the directory you want is always 3rd-last in the path as in your examples then all you need is this using any awk:

```
$ awk '{print $3, $6, $7, $8, p[split($8,p,"/")-2]}' file
user1 2021-09-07 2000 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08 1400 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09 1800 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```

Otherwise using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '{match($8,"([^/]+)/main/",a); print $3, $6, $7, $8, a[1]}' file
user1 2021-09-07 2000 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08 1400 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09 1800 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk '{match($8,"[^/]+/main/"); print $3, $6, $7, $8, substr($8,RSTART,RLENGTH-6)}' file
user1 2021-09-07 2000 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08 1400 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09 1800 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand why you would want the `sed` there, you can do it with just one `awk`. Of course, this assumes that you never have spaces or newlines in the folder names, and we can safely use whitespace as a field delimiter. Please edit your question and add a more comprehensive example if that is not true.

```
$ awk '{ 
            split($8,dirs,"/");
            dir="" 
            for(i in dirs){ 
                if(dirs[i+1]=="main"){
                    dir=dirs[i]
                } 
            } 
            print $3,$6,$7,$8,dir}' fileY
user1 2021-09-07 2000 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08 1400 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09 1800 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```

The trick here is using `split()` to split the 8th field into the `dirs` array, using `/` as the delimiter. We then iterate over `dirs` and keep the last array entry we find whose next array entry is `main`. Note that this means that if you have more than one occurrence of `main`, you will only match the last one.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach, using `rev`, taking advantage of the fact that the wanted folder is the third item in reverse using `/` as separator, assuming the folder name structure is consistent with the sample given (`<wanted folder>/main/summary.txt`):

```bsh
$ rev file | awk -F'/' '{ print $3,$0 }' | rev | awk '{ print $3,$6,$7,$8,$9 }'
user1 2021-09-07 2000 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08 1400 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09 1800 /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just as easily with sed, for that I define some helper shell vars to aid in the writing of sed code. Using GNU sed in it's extended regex mode.

based on the observations raised by @Ed Morton, the delimiters are now colon to avoid confusing with the ERE regex char |

```
_s='[:space:]'
s="[${_s}]" S="[^${_s}]" F="$S+$s+"
sed -Ee "
  s:^($F){2}($F)($F){2}:\2:
  s:/([^/]+)/main/$S+\$:& \1:
" file
```

Comment: "just as easily" is a bit of a stretch :-). Since you're already requiring GNU sed you could use `\s` and `\S` instead of those shell variables though. IMHO using a regexp metachar like `|` as the delimiter obfuscates the code and you should use a char that's always literal instead, e.g. `:`.

Comment: The GNU sed is there for its extended regex feature. The shell variables allow it to be made POSIX friendly. And insofar the usage of delimiters is very much a preference thing, one can use what they prefer.

Comment: Right, but I'm just saying since you're already using GNU sed there's no point in trying to make it POSIX friendly when you can't run it in a POSIX sed, may as well take advantage of other GNU features and just make it a self-contained concise GNU sed script and then you don't need to wrap it in double quotes and escape anything you don't want the shell to expand, e.g. `$`.

Comment: This point is well made and I agree with. I have Based on your observations, redid the delimiter code. But I don't agree with your previous assertion of using \s . The whole point of tgose variables was to make it usable for both cases.

Comment: What do you mean by both cases though? You cannot run that script in a POSIX sed as it's using the non-POSIX option `-E` and it's associated ERE syntax so using shell variables to make it more POSIX friendly doesn't help. If you want it to run in a POSIX sed then you could get rid of `-E` and change the `+`s to `\{1,\}`s and the `{2}` to `\{2\}`s but if you don't do that then using a shell variable instead of `\s` is of limited use (that might make it be able to also run in a BSD sed, but still not POSIX).

Comment: By changing the variables

Comment: Changing the variables would not let it run in a POSIX sed, it's the `-E` option and associated syntax that's not POSIX compliant. For any value of `x` this is POSIX compliant: `sed 's/x\{2\}//'`, and this is not POSIX compliant: `sed -E 's/x{2}//'`. The latter would only work in GNU and BSD seds.

Comment: IMHO you should just make the script GNU-only and take advantage of `-E`, `\s`, and `\S` and get rid of the variables, double quotes, and escaping of `$` in  the script as the result will be fairly concise while anything else (including making it POSIX-compliant or even just workable with BSD sed) is too lengthy/complicated to really want to use for such a simple task. Just my opinion of course...

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` nested grouping

```
$ sed -E 's|.*\s[0-9]\s\s(.[^ ]*).*([0-9]{4}-.*/(.[^/]*).*/.*/.*)|\1 \2 \3|' input_file
user1 2021-09-07  2000  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/main/summary.txt subfolder3
user1 2021-09-08  1400  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/main/summary.txt subfolder2
user1 2021-09-09  1800  /folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/main/summary.txt subfolder4
```